# How do you Resample daily with a conditional statement in pandas

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I have a pandas data frame below: (it does have other columns but these are the important ones)  Date column is the Index

```
           Number_QA_VeryGood  Number_Valid_Cells   Time  
Date                                                       
2015-01-01                  91                  92  18:55  
2015-01-02                   6                   6  18:00  
2015-01-02                  13                  13  19:40  
2015-01-03                 106                 106  18:45  
2015-01-05                  68                  68  18:30  
2015-01-06                 111                 117  19:15  
2015-01-07                  89                  97  18:20  
2015-01-08                  86                  96  19:00  
2015-01-10                   9                  16  18:50
```

I need to resample daily the first two columns will be resampled with sum. 
The last column needs to look at the highest daily value for the Number_Valid_Cells column and use that time for the value.

example output should be:  (1/2/02 is line which changed)

```
            Number_QA_VeryGood  Number_Valid_Cells   Time  
Date                                                       
2015-01-01                  91                  92  18:55  
2015-01-02                  19                  19  19:40  
2015-01-03                 106                 106  18:45  
2015-01-05                  68                  68  18:30  
2015-01-06                 111                 117  19:15  
2015-01-07                  89                  97  18:20  
2015-01-08                  86                  96  19:00  
2015-01-10                   9                  16  18:50
```

What is the best way to get this to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or you can try

```
df.groupby(df.index).agg({'Number_QA_VeryGood':'sum','Number_Valid_Cells':'sum','Time':'last'})
Out[276]: 
             Time  Number_QA_VeryGood  Number_Valid_Cells
Date                                                     
2015-01-01  18:55                  91                  92
2015-01-02  19:40                  19                  19
2015-01-03  18:45                 106                 106
2015-01-05  18:30                  68                  68
2015-01-06  19:15                 111                 117
2015-01-07  18:20                  89                  97
2015-01-08  19:00                  86                  96
2015-01-10  18:50                   9                  16
```

Update: `sort_values` first

```
df.sort_values('Number_Valid_Cells').groupby(df.sort_values('Number_Valid_Cells').index)\
  .agg({'Number_QA_VeryGood':'sum','Number_Valid_Cells':'sum','Time':'last'})

   Out[314]: 
            Time  Number_QA_VeryGood  Number_Valid_Cells
Date                                                    
1/1/2015   18:55                  91                  92
1/10/2015  18:50                   9                  16
1/2/2015   16:40#here.changed     19                  19
1/3/2015   18:45                 106                 106
1/5/2015   18:30                  68                  68
1/6/2015   19:15                 111                 117
1/7/2015   18:20                  89                  97
1/8/2015   19:00                  86                  96
```

Data input :

```
              Number_QA_VeryGood  Number_Valid_Cells Time
Date                                                     
1/1/2015                   91               92      18:55
1/2/2015                    6                6      18:00
1/2/2015                   13               13      16:40#I change here
1/3/2015                  106              106      18:45
1/5/2015                   68               68      18:30
1/6/2015                  111              117      19:15
1/7/2015                   89               97      18:20
1/8/2015                   86               96      19:00
1/10/2015                   9               16      18:50
```

Comment: I guess I should clarify a little more.  The time stamp I want is the one with the larger Valid cells and this could have been the 18:00 time stamp.  So it is not always the last one.  There could also be the same day 3 times or more.

Comment: Is this groupby daily?

Comment: @CRogers group by your `index`

Comment: I need one line per day.  this is producing two (if there are two days)

Comment: @CRogers dude, It is group by day .. Time is one column and I think you over look the data input as out put

Comment: my output is still coming up with the 2nd twice instead of once.          T=df[['Time','Number_Valid_Cells']].copy()
        T.sort_values('Number_Valid_Cells').groupby(
           T.sort_values('Number_Valid_Cells').index).agg(
           {'Number_Valid_Cells':'sum','Time':'last'})

Comment: @CRogers Could you please show your out put to me ?

Comment: I got it working I had to add T= to the front of it.  This piece of code is inside a function which is pulled by another script.  Thank you for the help @Wen

Answer (score 1):

You can use groupby sum for first two columns, if you have the values of `Number_Valid_Cells` sorted then

```
ndf = df.reset_index().groupby('Date').sum()
ndf['Time'] = df.reset_index().drop_duplicates(subset='Date',keep='last').set_index('Date')['Time']
```

```
                Number_QA_VeryGood  Number_Valid_Cells   Time
Date                                                     
2015-01-01                  91                  92  18:55
2015-01-02                  19                  19  19:40
2015-01-03                 106                 106  18:45
2015-01-05                  68                  68  18:30
2015-01-06                 111                 117  19:15
2015-01-07                  89                  97  18:20
2015-01-08                  86                  96  19:00
2015-01-10                   9                  16  18:50
```

Comment: happy holiday ~ :)+1

Comment: It is not always the last time stamp.  I need the time stamp from the row which corresponds to the larges Number of Valid Cells for each date.  I could have more than two time stamps per day. I also have the sum part working and am really just stuck on how to get the time stamp correct. Thanks for the help,